# Selenium : HtmlUnit UnexpectedTagNameException error with dropdown box

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

Currently, I am using HtmlUnit as my driver. With Selenium, I was attempting to write a dropbox choice selector, that can choose a state. as shown [image: Here]

I keep on receiving this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"
```

This error is not present whenever I use the chrome headless browser, just HtmlUnit.

What I wrote was this:

```
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("checkout_shipping_address_province"))).selectByVisibleText("Georgia");
```

Dropdown Box HTML:

```
<select placeholder="State" autocomplete="shipping address-level1" data-trekkie-id="shipping_province_field" data-backup="province" class="field__input field__input--select" aria-required="true" name="checkout[shipping_address][province]" id="checkout_shipping_address_province"><option disabled="">State</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Alabama&quot;]" value="AL">Alabama</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Alaska&quot;]" value="AK">Alaska</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;American Samoa&quot;]" value="AS">American Samoa</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Arizona&quot;]" value="AZ">Arizona</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Arkansas&quot;]" value="AR">Arkansas</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;California&quot;]" value="CA">California</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Colorado&quot;]" value="CO">Colorado</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Connecticut&quot;]" value="CT">Connecticut</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Delaware&quot;]" value="DE">Delaware</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;District of Columbia&quot;]" value="DC">District of Columbia</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Federated States of Micronesia&quot;]" value="FM">Federated States of Micronesia</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Florida&quot;]" value="FL">Florida</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Georgia&quot;]" value="GA">Georgia</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Guam&quot;]" value="GU">Guam</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Hawaii&quot;]" value="HI">Hawaii</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Idaho&quot;]" value="ID">Idaho</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Illinois&quot;]" value="IL">Illinois</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Indiana&quot;]" value="IN">Indiana</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Iowa&quot;]" value="IA">Iowa</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Kansas&quot;]" value="KS">Kansas</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Kentucky&quot;]" value="KY">Kentucky</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Louisiana&quot;]" value="LA">Louisiana</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Maine&quot;]" value="ME">Maine</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Marshall Islands&quot;]" value="MH">Marshall Islands</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Maryland&quot;]" value="MD">Maryland</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Massachusetts&quot;]" value="MA">Massachusetts</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Michigan&quot;]" value="MI">Michigan</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Minnesota&quot;]" value="MN">Minnesota</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Mississippi&quot;]" value="MS">Mississippi</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Missouri&quot;]" value="MO">Missouri</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Montana&quot;]" value="MT">Montana</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Nebraska&quot;]" value="NE">Nebraska</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Nevada&quot;]" value="NV">Nevada</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;New Hampshire&quot;]" value="NH">New Hampshire</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;New Jersey&quot;]" value="NJ">New Jersey</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;New Mexico&quot;]" value="NM">New Mexico</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;New York&quot;]" value="NY">New York</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;North Carolina&quot;]" value="NC">North Carolina</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;North Dakota&quot;]" value="ND">North Dakota</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Northern Mariana Islands&quot;]" value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Ohio&quot;]" value="OH">Ohio</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Oklahoma&quot;]" value="OK">Oklahoma</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Oregon&quot;]" value="OR">Oregon</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Palau&quot;]" value="PW">Palau</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Pennsylvania&quot;]" value="PA">Pennsylvania</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Puerto Rico&quot;]" value="PR">Puerto Rico</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Rhode Island&quot;]" value="RI">Rhode Island</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;South Carolina&quot;]" value="SC">South Carolina</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;South Dakota&quot;]" value="SD">South Dakota</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Tennessee&quot;]" value="TN">Tennessee</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Texas&quot;]" value="TX">Texas</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Utah&quot;]" value="UT">Utah</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Vermont&quot;]" value="VT">Vermont</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Virgin Islands&quot;]" value="VI">Virgin Islands</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Virginia&quot;]" value="VA">Virginia</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Washington&quot;]" value="WA">Washington</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;West Virginia&quot;]" value="WV">West Virginia</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Wisconsin&quot;]" value="WI">Wisconsin</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Wyoming&quot;]" value="WY">Wyoming</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Armed Forces Americas&quot;]" value="AA">Armed Forces Americas</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Armed Forces Europe&quot;]" value="AE">Armed Forces Europe</option><option data-alternate-values="[&quot;Armed Forces Pacific&quot;]" value="AP">Armed Forces Pacific</option></select>
```

Comment: can you share the html or any script of the drowdown then we say something raw..

Comment: Sorry about that, just added it.

Comment: one more thing jeff will you able to share the url if possible let us know that

Comment: try to click on element before `new select` like `driver.findElement(By.id("checkout_shipping_address_province")).click();`